Bridge network interface for VM (vmware) running on mac
I try to assign a private IP to VMware VMs (ubuntu) running on a macos host system.
I try to achieve this by assigning a single bridge network to each VM.
Connect Network Adapter options (inside VM settings) options I have are:

autodetect
wifi
-eterhnet (not available, since I run on wifi)

For whatever option I chose (autodetect, wifi) after restarting VM I keep getting the same IP on all VM when running the command:
- hostname -i

I have read this and that question, but I could not find the answer.
